# how to add the count(id), count(name) of query using alias

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I want to the add the counts that I'm getting from subqueries and assigning the alias to them. Is there any way to add them using provided alias only rather than using

```
select 
   ( select count(*)... subquery1 ) as s1,  
   (subquery2 ) as s2,  (subquery3 ) as s3, 
   add ( (subquery1 ) + (subquery2) + (subquery3)) 
from tableName
```

In the above query I need to call the subqueries again if I want to add the counts of them. Can we simply use the alias something like

```
select (subquery1 ) as s1,  
       (subquery2 ) as s2,
       (subquery3 ) as s3, 
       add (s1  + s2+ s3) 
from tableName
```

Comment: You need to use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: I think but subquery  will query again at the time of addition also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested query

```
Select *,(s1 + s2 + s3) as add from
(select ( select count(*)... subquery1 ) as s1,  
        (subquery2 ) as s2,  
        (subquery3 ) as s3 
 from tableName) AS T1
```

Comment: Answer for your query `Select s1,s2,s3,s1+s2+s3 as add from(
SELECT user_id,
       (SELECT Count(status) 
        FROM   delivery_header WHERE status = 's1')  AS s1, 
       (SELECT Count(status) 
        FROM   delivery_header WHERE status = 's2')  AS s2,
       (SELECT Count(status) 
        FROM   delivery_header WHERE status = 's3')  AS s3
FROM   user_details 
ORDER  BY s1 DESC) as T1`

Comment: Remove ; after desc and , after s3

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a different way, using a class for presenting your results.

```
public class MyResult {
    private Long s1;
    private Long s2;
    private Long s3;
    private Long total;

    public MyResult(Long s1, Long s2, Long s3){
       this.s1 = s1;
       this.s2 = s2;
       this.s3 = s3;
       this.total = s1+s2+s3;
    }
    // getter e setter
}
```

In the query (or named query) in JPQL, you can write:

```
SELECT my.package.MyResult(
   (subquery1),
   (subquery2),
   (subquery3),
) 
FROM tableName
```

In the code, you can call

```
List<MyResult> results = this.em.createQuery(...).getResultList();
```